# How to use rails rescue_from outside the controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception, rescue

- I am using GrapeApi and I am using service design pattern so I need to handle exceptions outside the controller, but rescue_from is only working inside controllers. - I am using `rescue ExceptionName` in almost every method and I found that I am not respecting the DRY rule. so I created a file `services/exception_handler_service.rb`. and tried `include ActiveSupport::Rescuable` and it's just being ignored and `extend ActiveSupport::Rescuable` and throwing undefined method rescue_from.

is there a way I can use rescue_from outside the controller?

Comment: Usually, the controller should be able to rescue from exceptions in models and service objects too because the controller is the instance that calls the models and the views. Can you please elaborate on your setup and why certain exceptions are not rescueable in your controller.

Answer (score 2):

Here example for you in plain Ruby as idea using [`rescue_with_handler`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Rescuable/ClassMethods.html#method-i-rescue_with_handler)

```
require 'active_support/rescuable'


class MyError < StandardError
end

class MyClass
  include ActiveSupport::Rescuable

  rescue_from MyError, with: :catch_error

  def method_with_error
    raise MyError
    puts "I am after error"
  rescue MyError => e
    rescue_with_handler(e)
  end

  private

  def catch_error
    puts "Catch error"
  end
end

MyClass.new.method_with_error # will print Catch error
```